# Multiple returns from one function with different assignment operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, is it possible to use multiple assignment operators for storing a function's output? Below is the format I commonly see, but instead I want `var1 += a` and `var2 = b`. Is this possible?

```
def example():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b

var1, var2 = example()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  You'll have to go the long way around:

```
temp, var2 = example()
var1 += temp
```